# AngularJs Filter / Doesn't update when called from controller

Tags: angularjs, templates, filter, controller, difference

I wrote a custom filter in order to translate my app, and it works great (it can also dynamically change language thanks to the 1.3.5 hint with stateful).

My problem is that when the filter is called from the template it work greats (both initalize & dynamic change) :

```
<p>{{ 'HOME_TITLE_TEXT' | i18n }}</p>
```

But when I call it from the controller it only initialize, and doesn't update when I change the language

```
// In controller
$scope.anotherTest = $filter('i18n')('HOME_TITLE_TEXT');

// In template
<p>{{ anotherTest }}</p>
```

I've also tried with ng-bind & ng-bind-html but it doesn't update either.

When adding an alert on the filter function, I notice that the filter is triggered way more in the first case.

Any clue on why controller declared filter doesn't update as often as the other ? And/or how I can force it to update ? (I've already looked at $apply, without results)

Note : the filter calls a service that update the dictionnary used (most of online tutorials did that)

```
// filter content
function filterFn(label) {
    return langService.getTrad(label);
}
filterFn.$stateful = true;
return filterFn;
```

Comment: when you changed language, this key 'HOME_TITLE_TEXT' won't change. so angular  watch can't trigger. but i think https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate support that kind too. Personally, I hard reload the page when user change the language.

Comment: The filter calls a service that update the dictionnary. I'll edit the question. But you're right as the dictionnary just init once with all languages. gonna try make a sub dictionnary with only one language and see if it changes. Wierd thing is that with the template definition ({{ expression }}) it works perfectly

Comment: Just tried your solution, doesn't change.

$Filters declared in controller still won't proc my filter when the language change, in contrast to {{ expression }} declaration